# What is considered "best practice" when making a quote memorable?

Tags: word-usage, quotations, readability

So I have this quote I'm working on:

> Information has moved from the tip of the tongue to the tip of the fingers.

There is an alternate version I've made that reads as follows:

> Information has moved from the tip of the tongue to the fingertips.

This quote has to do with how much we now rely on technology for gathering/reciting information.

My question is, which quote makes more sense, and which quote is more memorable? I like the idea of having `tip of the tongue` align with `tip of the fingers` but `tip of the fingers` just doesn't work as well as `fingertips`. Especially when you think of the internet being `the world at your fingertips`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in my experience, memorable quotes are usually more direct and often have a rhythm. Therefore, the second sentence is better: `Information has moved from the tip of the tongue to the fingertips`. It reverses the rhythm of `tip of the tongue` to `fingertips`, giving it a nice tone. Also, it is more direct than the second sentence.

The first one is not as good, because  the word, `tongue`, has one syllable and the word ,`fingers`, has two. Even though this sentence has parallel structure, the difference of syllables ruins the flow of the rhythm in: `the tip of the tongue to the tip of the fingers`. Read it out-loud a couple of times.

Because you want this to be a memorable quote, I would recommend choosing the sentence that has the best rhythm in its structure when spoken out-loud.

Answer (score 1):

Tip of the fingers is just as understandable, despite fingertips being the far more common usage.

As you point out, the symmetry of expression is much more memorable.  As is the cadence of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

To the extent that either alternative quote (my preference over "alternate" in AusE at least) will ever be memorable, *Information has moved from the tip of the tongue to the tip of the fingers.* would seem to be the more likely candidate.